# How to return whole object on data insert instead of id in mysql flask

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to know how to return the whole product data object like this

```
{
price_per_unit: 30,
product_id: 3,
product_name: "toothpaste",
uom_id: 2,
uom_name: "each"
}
```

instead of this only

```
{product_id:57}
```

server.py file code

```
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    request_payload = request.json
    product_id = products_dao.insert_new_product(connection, request_payload)
    response = jsonify({
        'product_id': product_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

insert_new_product function code

```
def insert_new_product(connection, product):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query=("insert into products (name, uom_id, price_per_unit) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    data = (product['product_name'],product['uom_id'], product['price_per_unit'])
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    connection.commit()
    return cursor.lastrowid
```

anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't do this.

The insert query will always return your primary key.

You should use the returned primary key to get your record back from you database then return it in the function as you wish.

**Edit**

you can use an ORM package that automatically create and retrieve you the created record check something like [Eloquent](https://pypi.org/project/eloquent/)